# Unable to preserve a global variable in the stack declared in ThisWorkbook code module

Tags: vba

I have a VBA project made of 4 "blocks" of code:

1. The first block of code is contained into the `ThisWorkbook_Open` event. Here, I create a collection that I would like to use everywhere in my project:

   ```
   Set myList = New Collection
   ```
2. The second and the third blocks are the methods of two user forms. Here I would like to be able to access my variable `myList` in order to add in it custom objects (instances of a custom class);
3. The fourth block, finally, is the code contained into a module through which I perform back-ground operations. Even here, I would like to access the collection to retrieve the objects I have added/modified.

What I did was declaring the variable as global on top of my code, namely on top of the `ThisWorkbook` general declarations since it's there the first time I will need to use my variable:

```
Dim myList As Collection 
Private Sub Open()
    '...
    Set myList = New Collection
    '...
End Sub
```

**WHAT I EXPECTED:** trying to perform the following statement contained into the Button-click event (*whose code is in another source file of the project tree, of course*) of one my forms should work normally, as the variable is globally declared:

```
MyList.Add MyObject
```

**WHAT HAPPENS:** the variable is not in the stack, so the compiler returns me the error `Object required`; of course I have checked this also with a watcher (that tells me the object is `Nothing`).

Could anyone help me to understand where I'm doing things wrong with this? Please don't hesitate to ask / edit if you think I'm missing something important.

**EDIT: project structure** (in yellow where the global variable is defined, in red where the global variable is tried to be called but fails as it's nothing)

[image]

Comment: Something you create in the `ThisWorkbook` is most likely not accessible throughout the entire VBA Project. What you would do in the `Open` event is redirect control to a `Module1` and then work with the collection there. So take your `Dim myList as Collection` out of `ThisWorkbook` and declare it as `Public myList as Collection` on top of `functional_code`

Comment: @vba4all you were right, it works fine now. Would you mind write it as an answer so I can accept it? I will edit my title accordingly, indeed the issue summary should rather be "declaring a global variable into ThisWorkbook does not remain in the stack", a stupid error that might still be tricky for some next users that might look for our Q&A exchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you create in the `ThisWorkbook` is most likely not accessible throughout the entire VBA Project. What you would do in the `Open` event is redirect control to a `Module1` and then work with the `collection` there. So take your `Dim myList as Collection` out of `ThisWorkbook` and declare it as `Public myList as Collection` on top of your `functional_code`.

Comment: Thank you @vba4all, I have finally added the `Public myList As Collection` in my `functiona_code` module and there created a `Sub initializeList` that I call from the `ThisWorkbook_Open` procedure to `Set myList = New Collection`. That works perfectly, thanks a lot.